# setting up android development with qtcreator on linux

Tags: android, qt

I want to develop an android app. I want to use qt native c++ programming. I donwloaded the android studio and ndk from the respective sites and unziped them into /usr/local/android/sdk and /usr/local/android/ndk. Then I donwloaded tools and platform tools, unzipped them and placed them into /usr/local/android/sdk/{tools, platform-tools}.

When I tell the qtcrator about the location of sdk and ndk, it complains that build tools and platform SDK are not installed. What else should I do?[image: qt configuration and the red marks are shown in the picture]

Answer (score 2):

When "Show Packages" > "Available" lists none of them... this [tutorial](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/12/28/qt-for-android/) suggests using the SDK Manager from Android Studio; the regular `sdkmanager` should also be able to install the missing packages. besides, paths below `/usr/local` might not be writable; better install eg. to `/home/google` and take ownership. the `android-ndk` directory ordinary is a sub-directory of `android-sdk` - which then can be updated automatically, too.

this would be the repositories:

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: The tutorial refers to "Qt installer", I used aptitude to install qt and qtcreator. I dont know what Qt installer is. So I could not follow the tutorial.

Comment: @RingZero. the relevant part is rather the SDK/NDK install, which is no different... you need the build tools and most likely, at least one SDK platform (API level). if QT creator cannot find any, most likely the repository URL is missing; you could copy them from Android Studio.

Comment: @RingZero. Easier if you use the Qt Online Installer. I would install to your home directory. It will not interfere with the Qt Creator installed by aptitude, but I would uninstall the one from apt, to avoid confusion. Also, Qt Creator is just an IDE, and you should not mix (any version of) it with the actual Qt versions, of which you may have multiple, including one installed with aptitude (make sure to install all development packages if you want to develop with that Qt version).

Comment: @RingZero you *have* to use the online installer, as the Qt provided via aptitude is *only* for compiling applications for your host system. Even if you get the SDK/NDK to work, Qt will still miss the Qt binaries for the android architectures

Comment: I get this error message while trying to build, dont understand what it means: "The installed SDK tools version (26.1.1) does not include Gradle scripts. The minimum Qt version required for Gradle build to work is 5.9.0/5.6.3
Error while building/deploying project android_test (kit: Android)
When executing step "Build Android APK"